# Refresh seekbar + textview in a listview

Tags: android, listview, textview, seekbar

I have a list view where each textview is supposed to show the value of the seekbar. I have got it working such that once the onStopTrackingTouch is called for a seekbar I update the corresponding textview. I would like for the change to occur as the user is moving the seekbar but I am having trouble doing the same as the listview doesn't refresh that often.

[image]

What would be an ideal method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is what I did , I defined a touch listener outside of getView , set it as the TouchListener for seekbar in getview. The TouchListener returns the view as an argument , I got the view's parent and the did a findViewByID search for the tectview and updated it.

Comment: what happen if in your list view having more then 15 row?

Comment: Ravi, can u please add code snap sort for this. update your above answer so that people understand  with sample demo people may thankful to U with Grete Work of U. coz most of people having problem when scrolling the lis it's can't maintain it's previous state.

Comment: +Milind will put it upsoon :-)

Comment: @AlexSanchez, I changed jobs, will need to spend some time searching for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can call [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)

on [OnSeekBarChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html)

Hope this help.

Comment: I tried it , but it seems to take the focus off the seekbar due to which the user is unable to seek

Comment: Okay gotcha. I tried this thing in my adapter and called setOnSeekBarChangeListener in getView method for each seekBar. Sorry for bad code formating, don't know how to do in Comment. Hope this answer your question.
 public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
   boolean fromUser) {
  TextView mProgressText = (TextView)     ((View)seekBar.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.progress);
  mProgressText.setText(progress + "");
}

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to achieve this behavior, when i override the ArrayAdapter´s `getView()` method, i set the SeekBar tag attribute with the position of the current item. so it helps me to extract the corresponding item when `onProgressChanged(...)` callback is executed. at the same time it lets me update the correspondant object inside which is contained in the adapter.

```
        sbProgress.setTag(position);
        sbProgress.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            View view = (View) seekBar.getParent();
            if(view != null){
                TextView tvProgress = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_porcentaje_numerico_obtenido);
                tvProgress.setText(progress + "%");
                MyAdapter.this.getItem((Integer)seekBar.getTag()).setProgres(progress);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

        });
```

Here is an image which explain what i mean[image]

I hope this can be helpful to someone.

Comment: Your solution works fine. My question is I've used my adapter to get this functionality, I've runned all of code snippets except  MyAdapter.this.getItem((Integer)seekBar.getTag()).setProgres(progress);  .setprogress is can not be resolved by android studio. I think I will update my getIem method but I am not able to do update. Can you show your getItem method for me.