# Seek bar not working in the listview

Tags: android

I have consecutive play buttons and seekbar in the Listview. When I click the play button in the the first row of listview, seekbar in the first row is activated. When i click the play button in second row of Listview, seekbar in the second row should be activated instead of  seekbar in the first row of Listview only action take place. can you help on this.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to say i can't understand. Show your code.

Comment: I cant get what you are asking Mr.Chennai, but i hope this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297791/refresh-seekbar-textview-in-a-listview